# Very Generic CSS Structure

Tags: css, syntax, styles, structure

I have what I can only assume is a pretty generic CSS queston...

Let us imagine for a moment we have the following:

```
body{
 background-color:blue;
 color:white;
 padding:2px;
}
```

Let us also assume we have this as well:

```
body{     
 color:white;
 background-color:blue;
 padding:2px;
}
```

With all that in mind, is there any particular structure, orientation or proper placement to CSS style elements-with respect to the placement of that element's styles and what line that style should be on?

Put another way, is there any "Standard" that dictates the background color in those two examples must be the first declaration made? Or is the arrangement of element styles completely arbitrary?

I came here to pose this seemingly trivial question to you masters of the CSS world as I am trying to fully understand CSS. It occurs to me, I can not find any documentation that specifically covers CSS syntax-with respect to proper writing form. Also, it seems to me that if CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet that the styles placed in/on an HTML element would best be served if they were to maintain some sort of consistency with the styling of a page/section/etc all alongside the HTML, right?

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in CSS that requires the styles in a single declaration to be in any particular order. It makes sense to organize them in some way, and Mature's way is as good as any. (I usually think of it as "create the element, then position it," meaning I reverse his 1 and 2.)

The exception to this is when you specify the same style in more than one way for the same declaration. If you look at mature's item 6, what he's saying is that some browsers won't understand `box-shadow` and will understand `webkit-box-shadow`. You should set it up so that browsers that understand both should use `box-shadow`, and you do that by putting it last. If you have two equally specific declarations, the one that is encountered last will apply. (For more information, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance).)

Answer (score 0):

Only one "standard" is possible in this case (with unambiguous order): You can sort properties **alphabetically** to help yourself and another have a fast search in.

OR more abstract: The overall logic of the sort "**from the General to the local and less important**". It is recommended to arrange the properties in the following order:

1. Position of the element relative to the others:
   `position`, `left/right/top/bottom`, `float`, `clear`, `z-index`.
2. Size and padding:
   `width`, `height`, `margin`, `padding`..
3. Border, it partially refers to the size and can be added to 1-st.
4. General design: `list-style-type`, `overflow`..
5. Colors, fonts and style design: `background`, `color`, `font`..
6. The property without prefix is written last.
   Example:
   first: `-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 100px 20px #000;`, then:
   `box-shadow:0 0 100px 20px #000;`. This is to ensure that the standard (final) implementation is always more important than the temporary browser implementation.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. But, I think  what I was mainly referencing in my original question was: If you are inside say the body element in your style sheet and you want to add a background color of blue, is there any rule that I am not aware of, that dictates that background rule MUST be on the first style for the body? I ask this because I see alot of different orientated styles for elements. I've seen some where they inconsistantly call the background style on an element on different lines, on different elements. I was just wondering if there was some precedent for that. Thank you!

Comment: Logical rule you can choose yourself or with team you work with. Technically properties is a just dictionary -- have no sense order inside same tag.

Answer (score 0):

In css, files are rendered from the bottom up, so whatever is below the other will be implemented. That is the only order based rules I can think of.

However, you can use "!important" to overide an element that is taking precidence lower in your css file. (If both styles have "!important", the lower one once again will take precedence.)

Just let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Orders inside tag properties have no render rules like "bottom up".. Also "!important" inside one one tag if you change order of properties have no sense too.

Comment: It does actually, if you have two of the same styles within one set of brackets, the bottom one will render. Of course you never want that, but if that case happens.  CSS always renders bottom up, no matter if you are refering to inside or outside the brackets.

Comment: Question not about "same styles", is about order of properties inside same selector.

Comment: Precisely, I am just stating the only possible permutations where order would matter.